# Is it a bad idea to attach inside mounted blinds to side of trim?

Tags: windows, trim

I would like to install some cellular shades.  I'd like to inside mount them, but my window recesses are very small - as little as 1/2".  For a shade that requires a recess of at least one inch, one thought I had was to replace the existing decorative trim boards with a simple 3/4" pine trim that is flush to the window frame.  This would give me 1.25" of recessed depth, assuming I don't mind attaching the shade partially to the window frame and partially to the trim.

What problems do you foresee with that approach?  I would obviously stick with lightweight shades and make sure the trim boards are attached well to the wall.

Comment: They aren't truly inside mounted if they project past the wall plane, but if you don't mind the appearance of a projecting trim box, there's nothing wrong with going that route as long as everything is securely mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I owned and operated a Budget Blinds franchise for two years.  As long as you comfortable with the support provided with you mount, you should be fine.  Cellular shades are so light.  The proper way to install them would be to mount L-brackets up through the window frame header and then window brackets to install the blind to the L-brackets.  If you call the company, they have a specialty bracket for you to use.

Comment: thanks - seems the real question is an aesthetic one of whether i mind a different style of trim board and also having the top part of the shade protruding slightly beyond the trim.

Answer (score 0):

Your fasteners are gonna be too close to the edges of your trim and of your wall, meaning the trim may be splitted by the screws, your wall drywall may just crumble, making for a very weak or faulty installation